# 'apt-get update' Error

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

I'm constantly getting a error and a warning on the output of `apt-get update` from yesterday night on my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit PC.

The significant part of the output of command `apt-get update` is following:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [64.4 kB]
  ...
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` is following:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

I experimented with the `sources.list` file yesterday and after some time reinstalled Ubuntu to 14.04.  Even after reinstalling I'm seeing this error.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

### Update 1

After un-checking *Unsupported Updates*, in *Updates* tab in `software-properties-gtk`, the 1st warning was removed.  So now I'm getting only following warning and error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

### Update 2

As suggested by Raphael (see comments), changing the download server in *Software and Updates* to **Best Server** solves the problem.

Comment: By reinstall do you mean that you formated your drive and reinstalled Ubuntu???

Comment: I had previously installed Ubuntu in 2 partitions: / (root) in /dev/sda2 and /home in /dev/sda4. I formatted the root directory (sda2) and reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 instead of previous, but kept my /home partition (sda4) and user directory same as before (including user name).

Comment: You only have two `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda4` ?

Comment: Actually I have 4 partitions.  In sda1 I installed Windows, in sda3 I reserved swap space.

Comment: Thats ok! Lemme check the sources.list

Comment: Your sources.list is absolutely fine. Try changing the server to something else by going to `Software & Updates > Server > Other > Select Best Server`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Raphael, I did exactly as you said and now no error occurred.  So it was a server problem.  Should've posted this question before reinstalling.  If you wish, add this as your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you getting error in Asia for updating ubuntu box u need to check this out
http://www.zsol.tk/2016/12/ubuntu-server-errors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error may be caused due to server errors. Changing the server tends to solve the issue. To do so, goto:

```
Software & Updates > Server > Other
```

and then select the best server